# Pandas Datetime Conversion from a particular ISO format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Many thanks for your help in advance.

I'm trying to convert a datetime which is a string in ISO Format to a datetime object. But have tried many methods without being successful. Please your help with this.

As an example, I have a dataframe which the column time is similar as shown below. This was extracted from a database and this was the output's format.

```
2018-12-04T04:39:26Z
2018-12-04T05:10:54.6Z
2018-12-04T05:17:32Z
2018-12-04T10:51:20.5Z
...
```

What I have tried so far (many attempts) but not being successful:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", errors='ignore')

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df.time = df.time.map(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'), format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
```

Thanks Again!

Comment: I tried those attempts before knowing there are two iso formats in the time list. How can I process this?

Comment: Which pandas version you use and which errors you get? `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` works for me with the examples you posted

Comment: Can you post the error it is producing (with the exact code you call)? What exactly is the problem with two different formats? When I paste this example data into IPython and just call `pandas.to_datetime` it works for all the entires, no errors, with correct results. What incorrect result do you get?

Comment: you probably need `pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')`. This should deal with both formats, and still coerce completely incorrect dates to `NaT`. In the first case, having two formats one will not match, raising an error, and with `errors='ignore'` this returns the input.

Comment: I found difficult to help without more code supporting the question, show us the   `head` of the real `Dataframe`.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I re-ran using ALollz and it worked! Thanks! pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to answer this before. In the end I just made a function that deals with different data inputs and also creates a dataframe with column names. Thanks ALollz for your comment regarding pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce').

So to convert the index from a string in an ISO format I established and followed this sequence:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[-1.8, '2018-09-14T13:36:00Z']], columns = ['current', 'time'])
df.set_index('time', inplace = True)   # make it your index by using the inplace=True
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')
```

After the conversion to datetime, check that dates are correct. You may need to specify the format if they are wrong read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but I believe that this response needs to be visible to ease people's lives.

If, as you said, it was extracted from a database, then you can do it directly at the moment of establishing your dataframe. Most pandas read functions have a parameter `parse_dates`. As said in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> Note: A fast-path exists for iso8601-formatted dates.

So even if you have 2 or more columns with dates, you can do it in an extremely easy manner.

```
df = pd.read_csv("x.csv", parse_dates=["Date1", "Date2"], names=["ID", "Date1", "Date2"])
```

Comment: I understand the question is about a particular format, but since people copy paste code from here, plese note: I have had problems with this setup where the format is not explicit. The issue is that for special cases the file might contain only dates with ambiguous dates (e.g. is `01 02 2021` really `Jan02, 2021` or is it `Feb01, 2021`) leading to a nasty bug

Answer (score -1):

The pandas.to_datetime() method has a 'infer_datetime_format' parameter, the doc says:

```
infer_datetime_format : boolean, default False
If True and no format is given, attempt to infer the format of the datetime strings, 
and if it can be inferred, switch to a faster method of parsing them. 
In some cases this can increase the parsing speed by ~5-10x.
```

So set infer_datatime_format to be true and leave the format parameter default, it works for me.

Here is my case:

```
>>> hours_df.head()
                            Open    High   Close     Low         Volume
Date                                                                   
2020-01-05T02:00:00.000Z  7457.9  7481.5  7431.3  7442.1  1147.57478328
2020-01-05T01:00:00.000Z  7374.8    7479  7374.8  7457.9  2709.45095966
2020-01-05T00:00:00.000Z  7354.9  7392.1  7354.2  7374.7   642.60575144

>>> hours_df.index
Index(['2020-01-05T02:00:00.000Z', '2020-01-05T01:00:00.000Z',
       '2020-01-05T00:00:00.000Z'],
      dtype='object', name='Date')

>>> hours_df.index = pd.to_datetime(hours_df.index, infer_datetime_format=True)

>>> hours_df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-05 02:00:00+00:00', '2020-01-05 01:00:00+00:00',
               '2020-01-05 00:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='Date', freq=None)

>>> hours_df.head()
                             Open    High   Close     Low         Volume
Date                                                                    
2020-01-05 02:00:00+00:00  7457.9  7481.5  7431.3  7442.1  1147.57478328
2020-01-05 01:00:00+00:00  7374.8    7479  7374.8  7457.9  2709.45095966
2020-01-05 00:00:00+00:00  7354.9  7392.1  7354.2  7374.7   642.60575144
```